# What is the difference between adding these strings?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic

**Program 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    char temp = 'a';
    str += temp + "bc";
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

*Unknown characters*

**Program 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    char temp = 'a';
    str += temp;
    str += "bc";
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> abc

Why are both the outputs different? Shouldn't both outputs be the same?

Comment: No, they should not be the same. The first one is undefined behavior. Pop quiz: what happens when you add a `char` to a `const char *`?

Comment: `char` plus `const char[]` is not the same as `char` plus `string` followed by `const char[]` plus `string`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: No possible encoding where `'a'` is 1 or 2? ;-)

Comment: for illustration, try this: cout << 'a' + "bc"; You just have a bunch of other stuff obscuring that error, so you think it's about std::string's addition operators, but it has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```
str += temp + "bc";
```

can be represented like

`str = str + ( temp + "bc" )`;

In the sub-expression `temp + "bc"` the string literal `"bc"` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character and has the type `const char *`. The value of the variable `temp` is converted to the type integer due to the integer promotions that for example in ASCII table has the value `97`.

So in the sub-expression there is used the pointer arithmetic. The expression `temp + "bc"` points to a memory that outside the string literal. So the result of the expression is undefined.

If you would write for example

```
char temp = 1;
```

then the expression temp + `"bc"` points to the second character of the string literal. As a result `str` would have the value `'b'`.

Or to get the same result as in the second program you could write

```
str += temp + std::string( "bc" );
```

As for the second program then in this statement

```
str += temp;
str += "bc";
```

there are used overloaded operators `+=` for the class std::string and objects of type `char` and `char *`. So these statements are well-defined.

Pat attention to that you should include explicitly the header `<string>`.

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Program 1 in this line

```cpp
str += temp + "bc";
```

1. first arguments of addition are evaluated
2. on right there is array of char: `const char[3]`
3. on left there is `char` which can be auto converted to `int`
4. `const char[3]` degrades to `const char *`
5. adding `int` (`97`) and `const char *` is doable, but results points beyond buffer range.
6. then you are using `basic_string::operator+=( const CharT* s );`, but argument is invalid. You have got buffer overflow.

Program 2.
Doesn't have this undefined behavior and operators form `std::string` are used.

Another reasonable version is:

```cpp
str = str + temp + "bc";
```

Now each addition will create a `std::string` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` class has `+` and `+=` operators overloaded, allowing you to use those to concatenate `std::string`s with each other, with individual characters and arrays of characters.

But just like in C, `"bc"` is not a `std::string` but a `const char [3]` (a constant array of 3 characters). Arrays are often automatically converted (*decay*) to pointers to their first elements. It happens here too.

`str += "foobar";` appends the characters pointed by the pointer one by one, until it hits the null byte that terminates the string.

You can add integers to pointers: `str += "foobar" + 3;` will append `"bar"` to the string.

In C++, `char`s are simply small integers. So `'a' + "bc"` actually means `97 + "bs"` (assuming your compiler uses ASCII, all common ones do).

This forms a pointer that's out of bounds of the array and causes undefined behavior.

The random characters you're seeing are the contents of memory located 97 bytes after the `"bc"` array, terminated by a random null byte that was in that memory.